# Is it still obligatory to obey a parent's command after they die?

Tags: fiqh, death, parents

For example, if my parent tells me to not play video games when I was a small child, is it still wajib to obey that command now that I am an adult and they have passed away when I was still a child?

Comment: The given example is rather silly. It depends on what kinds of orders you mean, if they  asked you to do something after their death and you agreed etc. you should do it as good as you can.

Answer (score 1):

No

What parents command to a small child is usually not meant to be valid for ever.

Parents will usually reduce their influence when a child enters the age of maturity. A grown-up person should in general be responsible and decide on his own; the parents would only command something they consider important enough at this situation. If they deceeded, they cannot decide any more, and the grown-up person is fully responsible to decide what to do.

Only God's commands can be eternally valid (and even some of His commands only refer to a certain situation or time).